# struts2 add hash (#) + version java component to url?

Tags: java, struts2

Hi I've a component java with struts2 and for every url it always adding e.g #1.0.0 at the end of url, Someone have any idea what happens?

Comment: Hey and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you be more precise about what your actual setup is and give us any hints on how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi what happens is that the struts add version of component pom at the and of url for example: http://anyurl.com.br/#1.0.0